# CSS animation causing z-index problems

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, z-index, css-animations

I have a weird conflict in my main.js file. I run a fade up animation on ".main-headline--left"

```
$('.main-headline--left').addClass('wow animated fadeInUp');
```

This works fine, but when I add a piece of code that makes nav-links active based on what page the user is on, the animation obstructs the logo which hangs off of the navbar (logo height > navbar fixed height). Here is that code:

```
if(location.pathname != "/") {
    $('.navbar-nav--split a[href^="/' + location.pathname.split("/")[3] + '"]').addClass('is-active');
} else $('.navbar-nav--split a:eq(0)').addClass('is-active');
```

I notice this only happens in Chrome. Is there perhaps a better way to organize my Javascript or a better way to write the code so that this problem is rectified?

Here is the css animation:

```
@keyframes fadeInUp {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(30px);
        transition: .1s transform, .1s opacity;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(0px);     
    }
}
```

I did not explicitly set z-index on containing elements. However, setting a z-index of 9999 on both the logo navbar does not fix the problem.

Comment: Extremely unclear, also even though the title is css animation there is no code to show what that animation is or what the relevent z-index is.

Comment: I've updated the question with the css animation used and the information about z-index in this case. This behavior may not have to do with z-index and may be a bug in Chrome, since these two pieces of code which have nothing to do with each other, cause my logo to be trimmed to the parent navbar container until the animation is finished running.

Comment: It would be much easier if you included all the relevant HTML and CSS; enough to recreate the problem. Especially the `is-active` class. All I can say at the moment is that the `opacity` may be causing the issue as it messes with the z-layers.

Comment: The class is pretty basic, but involves custom made mixins that creates a line from a pseudo element on hover. I really don't think the problem would be solved from looking deep into the inner workings of the code, since 1) they are straightforward and this is a complex problem resulting from an interaction 2) the two code pieces work fine, independently, and 3) the two code pieces work fine in browsers other than Chrome.

Comment: I am looking for information on Chrome bugs I suppose. I am wondering if anyone has had a similar problem when dealing with animations in Chrome.

Comment: Interestingly I have fixed my problem, but not in the way that I would have like to. I changed my jQuery selector to $('.main-headline--left, .secondary-headline__title').addClass('wow animated fadeInUp'). This means that the element below the main headline is also fading up, and now I have no flickering on my logo element. The interactions are really interesting here

Comment: If you could provide all your code in a workable demo, we can actually fix the problem. I don't think this will be a bug, just a simple layering issue which can be tweaked. At the moment, it's impossible to give you an answer.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/35a87xbj/1/ After much tinkering, I wasn't able to make this work in jsfiddle, but I tried my best. All of the code is at least there. I have realized that the transform on my anchor links and the transform on my headline, together, cause the blue logo to be cropped to the navbar until the animation is complete.

Answer (score 11):

today I ran into similar issue... I patched it by changing the value of animation-fill-mode for the class *animated* as below...

```
.animated
{
-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
animation-duration: 1s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: initial; //Changed from both to initial 
animation-fill-mode: initial; /*Changed from both to initial
}
```

Notably, setting the animation-fill-mode to *forwards* was causing my issue...

*animation-fill-mode: both* inherits both *forwards* as well as *backwards* property, so my trillionth z-index element got hid under the millionth z-index element...

Setting it to *initial* worked for me.

Comment: this should be the right answer! I've been trying to fix this for hours... working like a charm ;)

Comment: Solved it for me too. It was quite a head scratcher for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found a fix to my problem, but I have no idea why this solution works. By adding "-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;" to my logo element, my logo no longer gets cropped when the animation on my headline and the transition on my anchor's pseudo element are run on load. I was wondering whether anyone knows why this would fix this problem. My logo element never moves on the z axis. There is a jsfiddle in the comment section that shows the code

Answer (score 0):

@GughaG's answer is right if don't need forwards, but if you do need, try adding position: absolute -- fixed me right up!

Answer (score 0):

The answers here did not initially make it clear that the transformed elements cannot be siblings of each other and still retain z-index layering. Therefore, a top, middle and bottom layer animating would flip/flop all over each other and other elements in the page, for example a modal popup.

What needs to happen is a wrapping control layer that is not animated but holds the z-index order of things.

i.e. from this:

```
<wrapper>
  <child-1 /> <- animated element bottom layer
  <child-2 /> <- animated element middle layer
  <child-3 /> <- animated element top layer
</wrapper>
```

To this:

```
<wrapper>
  <child-wrapper-1>
    <child-1 /> <- animated element bottom layer
  </child-wrapper-1>
  <child-wrapper-2>
    <child-2 /> <- animated element middle layer
  </child-wrapper-2>
  <child-wrapper-3>
    <child-3 /> <- animated element top layer
  </child-wrapper-3>
</wrapper>
```

Where child-wrapper 1 has z-index of 1, child-wrapper 2 has z-index of 2 etc. and are NOT animated.

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pingram3541/8rdx9u2w/show